# MAX INT in C99?

Tags: c99

I'm going crazy in here, what is the "command" for the max int value? I want to put it in a variable but I dont want to put the specific number, I remember there is a Saved word for it.

Answer (score 4):

The macro `INT_MAX` is defined in `<limits.h>`. (It's there in all versions of the C standard back to 1989.)